# How do I store a function within an observable in Mobx v2.4

Tags: observable, mobx

I am have an observable array - items which store a list of item.

```
@observable items = [];
```

I push objects into the items array and one of the property in an object is a function.

```
items.push({
  id,
  refreshData // function
});
```

The above code wraps the refreshData function within an observable. I want to store the function - refreshData without any observable wrapper.

I believe in latest Mobx (@3), it is possible using observable.ref:

```
items.push({
  id,
  refreshData: observable.ref(refreshData) // function
});
```

However, I am using Mobx v2.4 and I do not have an equivalent of observable.ref. All I want is not to wrap the function within an observable. Has anyone done this before? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the API for v2.4 but I think you can use this way:

```
items.push({
  id,
  refreshData: extendObservable(refreshData) // function
});
```

Check out this example, [Modifiers on Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/modifiers.html).
Let me know if I am right.